# Angular nested routing ignores app base href

Tags: angular, routes, nested, href

I have an issue with Angular routing when the app is deployed.
On localhost, the base href is set to default : "/", but on production it's '/platform' so the url looks something like this : www.server.com/platform

My lazy routing is ignoring the base href, but normal doesn't. So when I go to /home, it's routed to www.server.com/platform/home.

But when I go to */sub/sub1/{id}* I am redirected to  *www.server.com/sub/sub2/{id}*.

How can I fix this?

Here's my main and lazy routing:

Main:

```
 RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
       path: 'home',
       component: HomeComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'sub',
        loadChildren: './sub/sub.module#SubModule', // lazy loaded
      },
      {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: 'not-implemented',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]),
```

And Lazy:

```
{
    path: '',
    component: SubContainerComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'sub1/:id/',
        component: Sub1Component,


      },
     {
        path: '',
        component: SomeOtherComponent,
     },
    ],

  }
```

I have tried using *APP_BASE_HREF*

Comment: What build command are you using for production? Have you tried using <base href="/platform"> in the <head> tag of your index.html?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, ng build --prod --base-href "/plaftorm" and --deploy-url "/platform". Unfortunately no results :(

Comment: Could you try this command ng build --prod --base-href /platform without the --deploy-url? If the deploy-url flag is needed, please add a trailing slash to the end of the path /platform/. And remove the trailing slash from the sub route so it reads like this: path: 'sub1/:id'. If that doesn't work could you post your app.module and app-routing.module along with the sub.module and sub-routing.module files? I'll be better able to troubleshoot with those files.